# Calculate admission prices of different days

Tags: c++, calculator

1. Children are admitted free on Sundays, and pay only $6 each, any other day
2. Adults admission is $12 any day, except on Tuesdays, when it is only $8
3. Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday are same prices.
4. How do I shorten Mon/Wed-Sat so the code isn't repeated and can be single-line?
5. Sunday and Tuesday prices vary.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int Children, Adults, tickets, persons, pricea, pricec, total_price;
char day;

cout << "Enter the number of Adults attending? ";
cin >> Adults;
cout << "Enter the number of Children attending? ";
cin >> Children;
cout << "What is the day of the week? ";
cin >> day;


cout << "The day entered is: " << day << endl;
switch (day)
{
case 'm': case 'M':
    cout << "Monday" << endl;
    pricea = 12;
    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 't': case 'T':
    cout << "Tuesday" << endl;
    pricea = 8;
    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 'w': case 'W':
    cout << "Wednesday" << endl;
    pricea = 12;
    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 'r': case 'R':
    cout << "Thursday" << endl;

    pricea = 12;

    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 'f': case 'F':
    cout << "Friday" << endl;

    pricea = 12;

    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 's': case 'S':
    cout << "Saturday" << endl;

    pricea = 12;

    pricec = 6;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
case 'u': case 'U':
    cout << "Sunday" << endl;
    pricea = 12;
    pricec = 0;
    total_price = (Adults*pricea) + (Children*pricec);
    cout << "Total price is: " << total_price << endl;
    break;
default:
    cout << "Not a valid day" << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable

Comment: The indentation looks wrong. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things that come to mind:

- Don't use `using namespace std;` as it leads to namespace pollution (e.g. name collision)
- Don't use `std::endl` unless you need to flush the buffer
- As you already noticed there is a lot of duplicate code and just like [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) states we don't want to repeat ourselves

Going for a simple rewrite while keeping mostly to your original code we could do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int kids, adults;
    char day;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of Adults attending? ";
    std::cin >> adults;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of Children attending? ";
    std::cin >> kids;

    std::cout << "What is the day of the week? ";
    std::cin >> day;
    std::cout << "The day entered is: " << day << "\n";

    switch (day)
    {
        case 'u': case 'U':
            std::cout << "Total price is: " << adults * 12 << "\n";
            break;

        case 't': case 'T':
            std::cout << "Total price is: " << adults * 8 + kids * 6 << "\n";
            break;

        case 'm': case 'M':
        case 'w': case 'W':
        case 'r': case 'R':
        case 'f': case 'F':
        case 's': case 'S':
            std::cout << "Total price is: " << adults * 12 + kids * 6 << "\n";
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Not a valid day" << "\n";
    }
}
```

This makes use of [Fall through cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) in the `switch` construct thus simplifying your code without overengineering it.